# Replace class between elements isn't working on first element

Tags: jquery

When i switch to any card i can't select back default card, why?

**HTML**

```
<div class="profiles_container">
    <div class="profile_card_selected">
        Default
    </div>
    <div class="profile_card">
        First
    </div>
    <div class="profile_card">
        Second
    </div>
    <div class="profile_card">
        Third
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".profile_card").click(function(){      
    $('.profiles_container').find(".profile_card_selected").removeClass("profile_card_selected").addClass("profile_card");
    $(this).removeClass("profile_card").addClass("profile_card_selected");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7eh5atd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're only attaching the click event listener to the elements with a class of `.profile_card`. Since the first element doesn't have a class of `.profile_card` initially, the click event isn't attached to it.

Without changing any HTML, the easiest way to work around this would be to [delegate the click event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to a common ancestor so that the class will be checked when the click event is fired (rather than when the event is initially attached like before):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7tbqmao9/)

```
$('.profiles_container').on('click', '.profile_card', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you could also just attach the event listener to all the children elements regardless of their classes:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/3k9uape7/)

```
$('.profiles_container').children().click(function() {
    // ...
});
```

---

However, the better approach would be to use a common class between the elements and then add an `.is_selected` class in addition to the common class. In doing so, the event listener will be attached to all the elements initially:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/g1xpyLod/)

```
$('.profile_card').on('click', function() {
  $('.profile_card').removeClass('is_selected');
  $(this).addClass('is_selected');
});
```

Updated HTML:

```
<div class="profiles_container">
  <div class="profile_card is_selected">
    Default
  </div>
  <div class="profile_card">
    First
  </div>

  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```